# Automapper C# Net Core - How can I map two lists of different structure to change the value of one field?

Tags: c#, list, automapper

I have 2 lists. I need to change the value of one field from the first list(Student) with its corresponding value from the other list(Countries).

```
public class Student
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Country {get;set;}
}

public class Countries
{
 public string CountryName {get;set;}
 public string CountryCode {get;set;}
}
```

**Student List:**

```
[
 {
  "Id":1,
  "Name":"John",
  "Country":"Canada"
 },
 {
  "Id":2,
  "Name":"Doe",
  "Country":"Japan"
 },
 {
  "Id":3,
  "Name":"Cool",
  "Country":"New Zealand"
 }
]
```

**Countries List**

```
[
 {
  "CountryCode":"CA",
  "CountryName":"Canada"
 },
 {
  "CountryCode":"JP",
  "CountryName":"Japan"
 },
 {
  "CountryCode":"NZ",
  "CountryName":"New Zealand"
 }
]
```

The desired JSON result should be:

```
[
 {
  "Id":1,
  "Name":"John",
  "Country":"CA"
 },
 {
  "Id":2,
  "Name":"Doe",
  "Country":"JP"
 },
 {
  "Id":3,
  "Name":"Cool",
  "Country":"NZ"
 }
]
```

Can I do this with Automapper? Is Automapper the right library for this?

Answer (score 0):

That seems overkill.  Can you just loop through the `studentList` and change the country to the matching item in `countryList`?

```
foreach(var student in studentList)
{
    student.Country = countryList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CountryName == student.Country)
                                ?.CountryCode
                                ?? student.Country // some other fallback if no match found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NewtonsoftJson](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to achieve this.

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("country.json");
var countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Countries>>(json);
```

write back to json

```
countries[0].CountryCode = "ABC"; 
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(countries);
File.WriteAllText("country.json", json);
```